# jQuery validation plugin not working after JQM page change

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm currently working on a mobile html5 project. I'm using [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) jQuery validation plugin to validate a login screen with a form. I'm also using jQuery Mobile, with the single-page template (I have pages in separate html files, but when changing pages JQM reads the file and injects the new page content to the DOM). Im forcing JQM to reload the page again in every page change in the app:

```
$.mobile.changePage("pageurl", {reloadPage: true});
```

The first page is the login screen with a simple form for username and password. Everything goes well in the first shot: the validation plugin complains if the submit button is pressed and some fields are empty. If all fields are OK and submit is pressed, I make a couple of ajax calls to WS, save data in the DB and the next page is displayed.

This is the code for the login screen:

```
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#login_screen", function() {  
        //This event fires every time we show this JQM "page".

        $("#id_index_form").validate({
            submitHandler : function(form) {
                user = form.user.value;
                password = form.psw.value;
                login(); 
            }
        });
    });

    function login(){
        //Calls the login WS  (ommited)

        //if login went ok, inject next page in DOM using ajax
        $.mobile.changePage("nextpage.html", {reloadPage: true});
    }
```

One important thing is that I can't use form built in mechanism, so a custom `login` function is called instead.

When in the next screen, if the user goes back to login, I change page again:

```
$.mobile.changePage("login.html", {reloadPage: true});
```

And now the validation plugin just does not work any longer. It does not validate, and when the submit is pressed, the form is cleared and nothing happens. The mobileinit event was fired again as expected, however. There are no errors in the console.

Is there something I'm missing? How could I "restart" the plugin? Maybe it still thinks the previous call didn't finish?

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:
I'm debugging the non-minified plugin js file, and it looks like the problem is the initialization it does in the `validate` call. In the first call, which completes successfully, the plugin creates a validator wich binds to the form, and it caches the validator. In the second call, I'd need it to bind a new validator to the new form, and instead it is returning me the old validator (binded to the old form).

Comment: Have you tried pulling ALL of your validation JS into one single `validate.js` file, making sure to link to this file on ALL of the pages that need it? This way, all of your JS will be loaded when the first login page is showed, and will persist throughout the other pages and will be available as needed.

Comment: The `jquery.validate.min.js` is already loaded. JQM loads the scripts and css in the first page, then when it changes page it injects only the content on the existing page. The scripts in the head seems to be cached, but anyway, I replicated every script tag in every page.

Comment: I don't mean pull in the `validate` plugin on every page. What I mean is, include your code for each page that you may need, (ex. `$("#id_index_form").validate({.....` for every validation rule/method in another file, and link to THAT JS file on every page. Make sense?

Comment: `.validate()` is normally fired once on DOM ready (& jQM init) to initialize the plugin.  If you're pulling in the form later with `ajax` as you swap content around, then it will never work.

Comment: @Sparky Validate is called correctly on init. The form is in the DOM when I change to the next page (but is hidden). Then it is reloaded again via ajax, and a new validate should be performed in the new form. The problem is this plugin is caching the previous validator and returning it in the second validate call (i'm debugging it right now)

Comment: @AdamD There's no linking problem, so I don't think your proposal would change anything (and by the way it looks like very bad design to me. I'd like to keep each screen validation code in each screen controller js file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

What was hapenning: I have no idea. All I know is this plugin binds to a form when `validate` is called and keeps binded to it as long as the form is in the DOM. Also it caches the validator, so subsequent calls to `validate` over the same form return the very same validator.

What I did: Before changing to the next page, I remove the form from the DOM.

Comment: `.validate()` is called _once_ and only once to _initialize_ a particular target form.  Once initialized, it's never called again.  So yes, if you remove a form or add another form, it needs to be re-initialized.

Comment: The problem is if you remove the Form from the DOM you won't have the ajax transition any more. That is something that gives the feeling of a real native app to the end user. IS there any other way to force jquery validation plugin to re-initiate or reset the validator?